# how to declare a bidimensional array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
var test = new string[3, 2];
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                for (int h=0; h<2; h++)
                {
                    test[i, h] = "DataRows: " + i.ToString() + " " + h.ToString();
                }
            }
```

but when I try to see what's inside of test I see this

[image: quick watch]

If I try to see what is in any item of the array I get an error:

[image: error in item in array]

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and what is the correct way?

Visual Studio 2022, Blazor Webassembly, .NET6.0

Thanks

Comment: where are you getting this information from ? If this is actually a dataset from DB then there are situations when debugger window does not show the correct information

Comment: As you can see, the data is created as such. It is not coming from the database, but the code itself. the first and second screenshots are from 'quick watch' option on visual studio. How would you debug this properly?

Comment: are you sure the screenshots fits the final result (after passing all the loop) of your code? i quickly ran your sample and my output has 6 entries as was to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code and your problem has nothing to do with arrays. Check your Blazor debug setup. Try with different browsers and check where you set your breakpoint.

If you look at your screenshot you'll notice the exception `VSCodeDebugProtocol.ProtocolException` - follow the exception.

Here's a screenshot of your loop completely functional while debugging a simple console app. The problem isn't your code - it's your debug state.
[image: console debugging screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

C# supports **multidimensional arrays** as well as the so-called **jagged arrays**

The following sample code shows how to use them both

```cs
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Multidimensional array  

            string[,] multidimensionalArray = { { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" }, { "delta", "epsilon", "zeta" } };

            for (int x = 0; x < multidimensionalArray.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < multidimensionalArray.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(multidimensionalArray[x, y]);
                }
            }

            // Jagged array 

            string[][] jaggedArray = { new string[] { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" }, new string[] { "delta", "epsilon", "zeta" } };

            for (int x = 0; x < jaggedArray.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < jaggedArray[x].Length; y++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(jaggedArray[x][y]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

For more information, please see

- [Multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)
- [Jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `List` data type with `foreach` loop more easily:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Add the above Reference first

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

list.Add(new List<string>(){"aaa", "bbb"});
list.Add(new List<string>(){"ccc", "ddd"});

foreach(var i in list)//outer list
{
    foreach(string j in i)//inner list
    {
       //your code here
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
}
```